# Android app crashing every second time in lollipop only

Tags: android, kill-process

I'm new to Android studio and i'm developing one location based app. Here, I need to close the app at some instance,so I called the finish(); function and killed the process in onDestroy()

Problem: Everything works fine in android 4.4(Kitkat) but crashes in Lollipop (Crashes at the second time of opening the app after install)

```
public void onClick(){
    finish();
}

@Override                   //------------after the finish(); called---//
protected void onDestroy() {
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
    to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    resulted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

     audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    locationManager =            (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                              public void onClick(View v) {

                                  str_from1=from.getText().toString();
                                  str_to1=to.getText().toString();

                                             str_from1 = str_from1.replaceAll("[^\\w]+", "+");
                                              str_to1 = str_to1.replaceAll("[^\\w]+", "+");
                                              new JSONTask().execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + str_from1 + "&destinations=" + str_to1 + "&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&key=API KEY");
                              }
                          }
    );
}
```

Comment: Post your crash logs, that should have information about the crashes...

Comment: Why are you even using `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());`. `finish()` itself closes the activity.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working, but you can try to call 'System.exit(0)' instead which is a nice way to close it

Comment: shoe logs of crashes

Comment: @DavidPeicho you shouldn't make jokes when he is trying to learn. Surya as Rohit said, there should be no reason to kill your pid. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In Lolipop, it is fine working for the very first time. But, If I tried to open the app after I pressed the home button or back button.. it crashes.

Comment: @Nick Cardoso .. Yes I removed that " kill pid".... Still it crashing at the second time.

Comment: Post what it is doing onCreate and onResume, seeing as thats obviously the point at which its dying

Comment: @Aditya and Neeraj .. I'm not using a emulator since my computer can't hold that heavy thing. So, I can't get the crash logs! Is any other way to find the crash logs?

Comment: @Nick I've posted the onCreate() things... and I didn't used the onResume in my code.

Comment: More important now is the logcat. At first glance besides the potential for NPEs, I also dont think you can call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); after setContentView and may be doing some network activity in the UI there

Comment: My computer dying on opening the emulator.. So only I can't get the logcat.. please anyone tell alternate way that works fine for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't need to kill the process. Calling finish() should be enough; it will destroy the current activity through its natural lifecycle, and if it's the last activity standing, the application will effectively quit.

For more discussion on why you should not go on that direction:
[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Regards!